# PHP Find Match in Array Key and Sum the Value

Tags: php, arrays

**Input:**

```
Array
(
    [ADDRESS CHECK FAILED, ADDRESS DISCREPANCY] => 716
    [SSN CHECK FAILED, DOB CHECK FAILED] => 15
    [DOB CHECK FAILED] => 139
    [NO ISSUES] => 189
    [DOB CHECK FAILED, ADDRESS DISCREPANCY] => 51
    [DOB CHECK FAILED, ADDRESS CHECK FAILED, ADDRESS DISCREPANCY] => 23
    [SSN CHECK FAILED] => 3
    [ADDRESS DISCREPANCY] => 33
)
```

I need to sum the value of any key that does not contain the phrase "SSN CHECK FAILED"

I am using this function:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = true) {
foreach ($haystack as $item) {
    if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
}
```

Like this:

```
foreach ($issues_totals as $key => $value){

    if (!in_array_r("SSN CHECK FAILED", $key)){

    $total_with_no_issue += $value;

  }
}
```

Where `$issues_totals` is the above array and `$total_with_no_issue` is the value I am looking for. The problem is that with this code `$total_with_no_issue` is returning **1169**, which is the total of the entire array. I want it to return **1151**.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_filter` to exclude any keys that contain the target string:

```
$valid = array_filter($array, function ($e) {
    return strpos($e, 'SSN CHECK FAILED') === false;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

and then simply use `array_sum` to fetch the total of the rest:

```
$total_with_no_issue = array_sum($valid);
```

This actually returns **1151** not **1159** as you mentioned, see https://eval.in/845367

Comment: This is the best, cleanest, most direct answer that uses the most appropriate functions (which for the record can be turned into a one-liner).  Using regex is utterly unnecessary.  I was going to post this as my answer until I passed it on my way to the textbox.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e33b34209a1c3c4f244a8a0f59fbc0ea6ca725b6

Answer (score 2):

I hope this one will be helpful too.

**Solution 1:**
[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/845381)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$array=Array
(
    "ADDRESS CHECK FAILED, ADDRESS DISCREPANCY" => 716,
    "SSN CHECK FAILED, DOB CHECK FAILED" => 15,
    "DOB CHECK FAILED" => 139,
    "NO ISSUES" => 189,
    "DOB CHECK FAILED, ADDRESS DISCREPANCY" => 51,
    "DOB CHECK FAILED, ADDRESS CHECK FAILED, ADDRESS DISCREPANCY" => 23,
    "SSN CHECK FAILED" => 3,
    "ADDRESS DISCREPANCY" => 33
);
$requiredKeys=  array_flip(preg_grep('/SSN CHECK FAILED/', array_keys($array),PREG_GREP_INVERT));
$result=0;
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if(isset($requiredKeys[$key]))
    {
        $result+=$value;  
    }
}
echo $result;
```

**Solution 2:**
[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/845370)

**Note:** This one is non-efficient in terms of performance but will work perfectly fine.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$array=Array
(
    "ADDRESS CHECK FAILED, ADDRESS DISCREPANCY" => 716,
    "SSN CHECK FAILED, DOB CHECK FAILED" => 15,
    "DOB CHECK FAILED" => 139,
    "NO ISSUES" => 189,
    "DOB CHECK FAILED, ADDRESS DISCREPANCY" => 51,
    "DOB CHECK FAILED, ADDRESS CHECK FAILED, ADDRESS DISCREPANCY" => 23,
    "SSN CHECK FAILED" => 3,
    "ADDRESS DISCREPANCY" => 33
);

$array2=  preg_grep('/SSN CHECK FAILED/', array_keys($array),PREG_GREP_INVERT);
print_r(array_sum(array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($array2))));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is two things:

1) Filter the items that their key doesn't contain the phrase you want to exclude:

```
$filtered = array_filter($arr, function ($item, $key) {
  return !preg_match( '#SSN CHECK FAILED#i', $key);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)
```

2) Sum the filtered items

```
$sum = array_reduce( $filtered, function ($a, $b){ return $a + $b; })
```

Note: I'm using anonymous functions and the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` flag, thought that you might use PHP 5.6+